# ¿Como colapsar (ocultar) para después mostrar el colapsado?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Como la primera llamada a colapsar es ocultar, quiero colapsar (ocultar los elementos) para después usar el `collapse` en su lugar.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <tr class="costos_collapse fila_grupos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".grupo1_collapse">
    <td class="nombre_grupo" colspan="3">Terreno <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="costos_collapse grupo1_collapse fila_cuenta"><td class="nombre_cuenta">Terrenos 1</td><td class="alineaNumero">300</td><td class="alineaNumero">1.300</td><td class="alineaNumero">1.000</td><td class="alineaNumero">333,33</td></tr>
  
  <tr class="costos_collapse fila_grupos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".grupo2_collapse">
    <td class="nombre_grupo" colspan="4">Terreno <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="costos_collapse grupo2_collapse fila_cuenta"><td class="nombre_cuenta">Terrenos 2</td><td class="alineaNumero">400</td><td class="alineaNumero">6.300</td><td class="alineaNumero">5.000</td><td class="alineaNumero">13,33</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**
No funciona Hide

```
$("collapse").collapse("hide");
```

Comment: Re define bien tu pregunta, no es lo suficientemente clara para entenderla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu pregunta puedo ver los siguientes errores:

- El selector `$("collapse")`, no existe.
- El metodo [`.collapse("Hide")`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-hide), no es valido.

### Solución:

Supongamos que quieres ocultar el elemento con clase `grupo1_collapse`, entonces la sintaxis correcta sería:

```
$(".grupo1_collapse").collapse("hide");
```

Demo:

```js
$(".grupo1_collapse").collapse("hide");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <tr class="costos_collapse fila_grupos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".grupo1_collapse">
    <td class="nombre_grupo" colspan="3">Terreno <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="costos_collapse grupo1_collapse fila_cuenta"><td class="nombre_cuenta">Terrenos 1</td><td class="alineaNumero">300</td><td class="alineaNumero">1.300</td><td class="alineaNumero">1.000</td><td class="alineaNumero">333,33</td></tr>
  
  <tr class="costos_collapse fila_grupos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".grupo2_collapse">
    <td class="nombre_grupo" colspan="4">Terreno <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="costos_collapse grupo2_collapse fila_cuenta"><td class="nombre_cuenta">Terrenos 2</td><td class="alineaNumero">400</td><td class="alineaNumero">6.300</td><td class="alineaNumero">5.000</td><td class="alineaNumero">13,33</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: si entiendo claro, gracias